# Kotlin (Mutable)List

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

If you access a Java value of type `List<[Some Type]>` in Kotlin, you will get the type `(Mutable)List<[Some Type]!>!`.

e.g.:

Java code:

```java
public class Example {
    public static List<String> getList() {
        return Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    }
}
```

Kotlin code:

```
val list = Example.getList()
// list is of type (Mutable)List<String!>!
```

Here is, how IntelliJ shows it:

[image: IntelliJ type hint]

However, if you want to make your own variable of this type like so:

```
val list2: (Mutable)List<String>
```

Then IntelliJ will correctly highlight the type but will give the error `Unexpected Tokens`.

What is this `(Mutable)List`?

Comment: See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an IntelliJ IDEA tooltip that shows that the type of this list can be either MutableList or List, as `Example.getList()` is defined in Java, which means it can return either type of the list.

Also, the same happens to String: you don't know anything about the list's String nullability, as it is returned from Java, so String looks like `String!` meaning 'maybe it's null, but or maybe not' without affecting compilation (i.e. on such `String!` values you can both invoke methods without a null-check and actually make a null-check - no warnings will appear in neither case).

Comment: `Any!` is used for calls to Java code where there is no @Nullable or @NotNull defined for a specific variable. This usually happens from Java code, because it's always defined in Kotlin. That also means Kotlin won't be able to complain about null-safety, because it doesn't know whether it's null or not. If you get null at runtime, it will still crash though.

Answer (score 3):

There is no type `(Mutable)List` in Kotlin.

This serves as an indication that the type of list returned by `Example.getList()` 
will not be decided at *compile time* but it will be decided at *run time*. 
In your case it will be `List` and not `MutableList` because `Arrays.asList()` returns a [`FixedSizeList`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/FixedSizeList.html).

If you implemented `Example.getList()` like this:

```
public static List<String> getList() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
    return list;
}
```

then at *runtime* the type of your `list` would be `MutableList`.

Answer (score -1):

MutableList is a interfece in kotlin. 
To declare a variable we need to use class like as

```
    val list2: ArrayList<String>
```

@Josef Zoller

Comment: `val: list: MutableList<String>` is also allowed.